# How do I setup up Authentification Testing of API Endpoints in Laravel using Auth0

Tags: php, laravel, auth0, codeception

I am attempting to set up from functional testing in Laravel using the Codeception framework.

Here's what I need to do:
I am using Laravel as an API server. API calls require authentication for which I am using Auth0.
Different API endpoints require different scopes from Auth0.
The frontend applications which will provide these scopes are part of a larger ecosystem and are not to be tested at this point.

How do I set up tests for my API that uses the scopes from Auth0 for each endpoint?
Any ideas? Maybe there's a way to mock the Auth0 responses? If so, how would I go about this?
Thanks in advance.

So far I have managed to use a separate Machine-to-Machine application to auth in the tests but they do not provide scopes.

Comment: Have you tried postman its a good platform to test API.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have tested the API with Postman but what I am attempting to do is create a codeception suite of tests.